# Access VBA - All checkboxes on form have been checked

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am relatively new to Access VBA and have a form that has around 30 checkboxes on it. When saving the form I want to ensure that all checkboxes have been ticked (set to true). The tickboxes have all got names SC1, SC2....SCN Is there a way to loop through each control and see if it has been set to true?
This is what I have tried but it doesnt seem to read the tickbox -

```
Private Sub Validate_Data(rstTop)
Dim n As Integer
Dim count As Integer
count = 0

For n = 1 To rstTop
    If Form.Controls("SC" & n).Value = False Then
    count = count + 1
    End If
Next
If count <> 0 Then
MsgBox "Not all Questions have been ticked, please tick and add comments", vbInformation, _
        "More information Required"

Else
End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, it worked for me.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Function Validate_Data() As Boolean
    Dim ctl As Control
    Validate_Data = True             'initialize
    For Each ctl In Me.Form.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
            If (ctl.Name Like "SC*") And (ctl.Value = False) Then
                MsgBox "Not all Questions have been ticked, please tick and add comments", vbInformation, _
                        "More information Required"
                Validate_Data = False 'something isnt checked
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next ctl
End Function

Private Sub cmdGo_Click()
    Validate_Data
End Sub
```